# IIS 8.5 access specific file ends in 403.14

Tags: iis, http-status-code-403, iis-8.5, virtual-directory, directory-listing

In IIS I created a virtual directory to my media asset folder, which contains all images for my application.
For some reason I can't access images in one subdirectory directly, it ends in http error 403.14.

Images in other subdirectories are displayed correctly.
We don't want to enable directory listing.

Comment: Make sure that image directory in question has the same permissions as the other image directories having.

Comment: virtual directory and app pool are running on same user. this user is the main administrator of the server.